# android scrollView max scroll

Tags: android, limit, scrollview

Is there a way to add a range of scrolling to a scrollView? I've done a screen where user can drag views and I want to limit the possibility of dragging them down to some coordinates and modify those coordinates at runtime according to the number of object from view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some code like this:

```
if(scrollView.scrollY() >= limit)
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

To disable scrolling if user tries to scroll further than limit that you decided.

Edit: here, limit is coordinates typed int